# Airflow Dag Statuses Inconsistent in Webserver

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow

I have an Airflow cluster up, configured to use the CeleryExecutor and a Postgres backend.

For some reason, the statuses of the DAGs on the Webserver UI are inconsistent every time I refresh. Upon each refresh, it shows many different things such as the DAG not available in the webserver dagbag object, or black statuses, or hiding the links on the right.

It changes on each refresh.

Here are a few screenshots:

- [Webserver UI 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZBy5.png)
- [Webserver UI 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjIe3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Run airflow web-server in debug mode than you can get this resolved

```
airflow webserver -p <<port>> -d
```

The problem seems to be some dynamic code changes happening on new dag creation and hence production mode flask server is not patching it through